# Progress bar-how to add markings/reticle

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have a vertical progress bar in Bootstrap (implemented in a React component) that I would like to put horizontal markings on. In other words, right now the bar is filled in up to the current expected yield, and I would also like to mark the target yield with a horizontal line across the progress bar. Any ideas?

```
<div className="w-25 m-1">
                <div className="progress progress-bar-vertical ">
                    <div
                        className="progress-bar"
                        role="progressbar"
                        aria-valuenow={yieldInKG}
                        aria-valuemin="0"
                        aria-valuemax={maxValue}
                        style={{ height: '{ barHeight }%' }}>
                        <span>{percentage}%</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: The code below can do the job using native Bootstrap classes alone. Instead of the `bg-light` you can try the `bg-secondary` class.

Here's the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <div class="progress progress-bar-vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%</div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-light" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: .3%"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: That results in horizontal bars.

Comment: The reason I used the horizontal bar in my code snippet is because you used customized Bootstrap without providing the custom code in your example. So, to show a working example I used the horizontal bar. I hope you have the skills to make the minor adjustment needed for your vertical bar. Most of the code will remain identical for that.